# Terminate signal from remote to local machine( jmeter machine) in perl

Tags: perl, jmeter

I have Perl script, which is at remote machine and I am calling it from local system (I am calling the remote script by using autoshell property of Jmeter). There is no issue in the perl script. I want to Implement the new functionality, without changing anything in local machine rather I have to do some changes in perl script. I am just posting small part of script.

```
if($BALANCE_N == $newWalletBalance){
    print "Previous wallet Balance was:$prevWalletBalance  New walletBalance is:$newWalletBalance\n";
    print "Total cost and sale price respectively: $totalCostPrice and $totalSalePrice\n\n";
    return 0;
}
else{
    print "Error: Wallet Balance in CDR and DB is not matching\n";
    return 1;
}
```

if "if statement is successful, it should go ahead in the script make it pass", if it entered into else part then my script should return some terminate kind of signal to local machine and should mark the script as failed. I have tried with return and exit statement but it is not that useful, any other way in the Perl to implement my functionality.

Comment: `not that useful?` What exactly do you want in output in case code goes to `else` block?

Comment: It should send the terminate signal to the jmeter autoshell in else blcok

Comment: Won't the shell terminate automatically once you `exit` the script? Then it may be good enough to return a non-zero exit value (by passing it to `exit`).

Comment: Perhaps if someone who knows jmeter could tell those of us who know Perl what "the terminate signal to the jmeter autoshell" is, we could tell you how to send it from Perl.

Comment: ok.. let some jmeter expert to get back on this

Answer (score 0):

I normally use this:

```
} else {
    print "Error: Wallet Balance in CDR and DB is not matching\n";
    exit(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can send `Shutdown` message via UDP to the host where JMeter is running at port 4445. Not sure how to properly do it in Perl, you can see [ShutdownClient.java](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/jmeter/trunk/src/core/org/apache/jmeter/util/ShutdownClient.java) for Java implementation
2. If you call your script via JMeter's [OS Process sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#OS_Process_Sampler), it has "Check Return Code" option
3. If JMeter can read STDOUT and/or STDERR you can use [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) to check script output. JMeter provides several more [assertion types](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps) which allow to set pass/fail criteria quite flexibly.

Comment: Hi Dmitri.. Thanks for your response.. it is quite useful...as you said I think we are not calling Script via OS process sampler, also your third point is valid I am thinking , I am doing it based on return 1 and return 0 from my perl script but in response assertion where I will compare return values and with whom

Comment: One more thing is Perl script is at remote machine and I am calling it from local machine, I am calling the script using autoshell command of jmeter, my point is Jmeter doesn't have control on perl script , if it returns the success or failure,  jmeter is ignoring the result and going ahead with other execution.

Comment: What is "autoshell" command of JMeter?  I don't see anything regarding it in documentation/source

Comment: It is shell command only.. which I am passing in my test case

Comment: "sh cdr.pl" which will connect to remote machine and execute the things over there

Comment: Hi Dmitri. Any comments on this.. please help

Comment: I don't have any other ideas apart form listed in the original answer. How do you call this `sh cdr.pl` script from your JMeter test?